# Where is the mistake with my proof that $\sum\limits_{m=0}^{a-1}\operatorname{Li}_s(ze^{\frac{2\pi im }{a}})=a^{1-s}\operatorname{Li}_s(z^a)$

Tags: special-functions, polylogarithm

I tried to prove that $$\sum_{m=0}^{a-1}\operatorname{Li}_s(ze^{\frac{2\pi im }{a}})=a^{1-s}\operatorname{Li}_s(z^a)$$

where $\operatorname{Li}_s(x)$ is [Polylogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

$$\sum_{m=0}^{a-1}\operatorname{Li}_s(ze^{\frac{2\pi im }{a}})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n^s}\sum_{m=0}^{a-1}e^{\frac{2\pi imn }{a}}$$

$$\sum_{m=0}^{a-1}\operatorname{Li}_s(ze^{\frac{2\pi im }{a}})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n^s}\frac{1-e^{2\pi in}}{1-e^{\frac{2\pi in }{a}}}=0$$

so where is the mistake and any way how to prove this formula ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so where is the mistake

If $n$ is a multiple of $a$, then

$$\sum_{m=0}^{a-1} \exp \left(\frac{2\pi i mn}{a}\right) = \sum_{m=0}^{a-1} 1 = a.$$

Comment: ohhhh my god why i forgot that ?!!!:),thanks.

Comment: The OP didn't say any thing 'special' about $\large a$.